# Joda time hard coding does not work in different time zone

Tags: java, jodatime

Joda time hard coding does not work in different time zone. I have hard coded Joda time in following way so that I can provide static date-time to my Junit test case.

```
LocalDateTime fixedDateTime = new LocalDateTime(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minuteOfHour, secondOfMinute, 0, ISOChronology.getInstance("Canada/Pacific")));

DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(fixedDateTime.toDate().getTime());
```

But when you try to get current date-time using following API , it may not result in exact fixed date as above.

```
DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("Canada/Pacific"));
```

This date can be even one day prior or next day with respect to fixed date depending on which time-zone you are running the code. 
This can be frustrating because your test cases will passing locally but when deployed to virtual cloud machines, it may fail your test cases on those virtual cloud machines because they might on totally different time zone.

Comment: It's hard to give an answer without knowing what you are expecting to happen, under what circumstances.

Comment: You could probably have avoided the downvotes by rephrasing "does not work" to "I can't get it to work"

Answer (score 2):

[Javadoc of that constructor of `LocalDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#LocalDateTime(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20org.joda.time.Chronology)) (emphasis mine):

> Constructs an instance set to the specified date and time using the specified chronology, **whose zone is ignored**.

Use a `DateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`:

```
DateTime fixedDateTime = new DateTime(
    year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth,
    hourOfDay, minuteOfHour, secondOfMinute, 0,
    ISOChronology.getInstance("Canada/Pacific")));

DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(fixedDateTime.getMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andy for your reply. You are right about LocalDateTime not using zone. But I ended up using LocalDateTime since I wanted to hard code date to the second. But I did find a solution to take care of offset generated by the zone. Here is my code

```
private LocalDateTime setJodaTime(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour, int secondOfMinute) {
        LocalDateTime fixedDateTime = new LocalDateTime(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minuteOfHour, secondOfMinute, 0, ISOChronology.getInstance(DateTimeZone.forID("Canada/Pacific")));
        long millisWithoutTimeZone = fixedDateTime.toDate().getTime();
        // fixed Joda millis
        DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(millisWithoutTimeZone);
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("Canada/Pacific")).toLocalDateTime();
        // get time zone offset
        long offset = localDateTime.toDate().getTime() - millisWithoutTimeZone;
        // reverse the offset
        offset = (-1) * offset;
        DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(millisWithoutTimeZone + offset);
        LocalDateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("Canada/Pacific")).toLocalDateTime();
        return currentDateTime;
    }
```